# Как упорядочить ящики с усами по возрастанию на графике?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, график

На основе [таблицы](https://yadi.sk/i/3teWjGq3OZqxLA) построен график ящиков с усами.
Как упорядочить города слева направо по возрастанию значения относительной заболеваемости?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\cinem\Desktop\нир\3-6.xlsx')
(df.pivot_table(columns='town_name', index='cld_year',
                values='относительная заболеваемость', aggfunc='mean', fill_value=0)
   .plot.box(rot=90, figsize=(16,10)))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: график]

Comment: я так понимаю, по медиане? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912634/how-can-i-sort-a-boxplot-in-pandas-by-the-median-values Единственное, в примере старая реализация boxplot, так что будьте внимательны.

Comment: корпоративный файрвол не позволяет скачать ваш файл... Можете выложить на другой файлообменник?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = df.pivot_table(columns='town_name', index='cld_year',
                   values='относительная заболеваемость',
                   aggfunc='mean', fill_value=0)
idx = r.mean().sort_values().index
r = r[idx]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,10))

r.plot.box(rot=90, ax=ax)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(), r.mean(), color='orange')
ax2.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
plt.legend(['mean'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Анна, добавил среднее значение на графике...